# Not creating table using Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am inserting data into database using Spring MVC and Hibernate but when i am first time running my project its not generating tables using hibernate.

My Entity Class:

```
package com.cts.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="RegistrationDetails")
public class RegistrationDetails 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private String RegistrationId;

    @Column
    private String firstname;
    @Column
    private String lastname;
    @Column
    private String address;
    @Column
    private String emailid;
    @Column
    private String password;
    @Column
    private Long contactno;

    public String getRegistrationId() {
        return RegistrationId;
    }
    public void setRegistrationId(String registrationId) {
        RegistrationId = registrationId;
    }


    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getEmailid() {
        return emailid;
    }
    public void setEmailid(String emailid) {
        this.emailid = emailid;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public Long getContactno() {
        return contactno;
    }
    public void setContactno(Long contactno) {
        this.contactno = contactno;
    }


}
```

My Dispatcher Servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd"

    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cts.*" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <mvc:resources location="/" mapping="/**" />
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        id="DataSource">

        <property value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" name="driverClassName" />

        <property value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/opop"
            name="url" />

        <property value="root" name="username" />

        <property value="root" name="password" />

    </bean>

    <!-- <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        setting maximum upload size
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000000" />
    </bean> -->

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
        id="newSessionFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">

            <list>
                <value>com.cts.entity.RegistrationDetails</value>
                <value>com.cts.entity.LoginDetails</value>
                <value>com.cts.entity.RegisterationDetails</value>

            </list>

        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">

            <props>

                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
        id="transactionManager">

        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="newSessionFactory" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="h" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate"
        autowire="constructor" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <!-- <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="message" />
    </bean> -->


</beans>


Hibernate not generating tables.I am inserting data into database using Spring MVC and Hibernate but when i am first time running my project its not generating tables using hibernate.
```

Answer (score 0):

In hibernateProperties, set the property hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to create-drop

```
<property name="hibernateProperties">

            <props>

                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
```

This will create the tables the first time you run the application. In the subsequent run, you can set the property to update if you are updating any existing tables. But in case, if you add any new table, then you need to again give create-drop.

Comment: Gaurav I have changed it n now m getting this error-  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cts.entity.RegistrationDetails

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.cts.*" />` to `<context:component-scan base-package="com.cts" />.`

You may also need

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />.
```

Just to add to answer given by Gaurov, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto set to "update" will create new tables for your new entities(that are not already on db), create-drop will drop them after you stop the app.